# how to do a input validation properly

Tags: java, validation, input, histogram

I'm trying to do a input validation for my histogram, so if a user reads in a minus number it should say Enter a positive number. For example the user enters -5, a error message pops up saying enter a positive number and then the next line says enter the next student mark which is going to be a positive number. My problem is when I enter -5 and the next line I enter is going to be a minus my code stops running, it suppose to stop at when the user enters a number that is over 100 which I declared in my while loop

**This is what the result looks like:**

Read in a mark

3

Enter the next student mark

43

Enter the next student mark

-5

Error! Enter a positive integer

-89

Total number of marks entered is 2

0-29: 
*

30-39:

40-69:
 *

70-100:

**This is what I expected it to look like:**

Read in a mark

-20

Error! Enter a positive integer

-30

Error! Enter a positive integer

40

Enter the next student mark

70

Enter the next student mark

-5

Error! Enter a positive integer

90

Enter the next student mark

101

Total number of marks entered is 5

0-29: 
*

30-39: 
*

40-69: 
*

70-100:
**

This is what I used

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Read in a mark");
 mark = input.nextInt();
 if(mark < 0) {
     System.out.println("Error! Enter a positive number"); 
     mark = input.nextInt();
 }
 while (mark <= 100 && mark >= 0) {
```

never mind the while loop part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle negative values is to replace the if clause with while clause as follows:

```
while (mark < 0) {
    System.out.println("Error! Enter a positive number"); 
    mark = input.nextInt();
}
```

Otherwise the value following the first negative value will never be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
while(mark < 0) {
    System.out.println("Error! Enter a positive number"); 
    mark = input.nextInt();
}
```